# How to search SQL db for table names then echo all names

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to output the table names. Getting error on line where while statement is.

```
   $queryTable = "SELECT  * FROM 'db_name'.sys.tables";
   $result = $con->query($queryTable);

   while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $table[0];    
     }
```

Comment: Use backticks `\`` instead of single-quotes `'`.  Should be `SELECT  * FROM \`db_name\`.sys.tables`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: I tried the back ticks thing an still getting same error...

Answer (score 1):

This is not mysql syntax. There are two ways you can do it in mysql.
First one is simply use `show tables` query. this will give you all table names.
If you want more details, you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` table- in there you can get all details on the table (see more info here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)

Comment: makes sense, I changed my query to :  $queryTable ="INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"; there is same error on my sql_fetch_arry(). Not sure to to write that in php and return to screen. sry newbie here. haha.

Comment: It should be `$queryTable = "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"`